# How could my "tumbler field" steer projectiles away from its user?

Tags: science-based, nanotechnology, firearms, flight

In order to allow melee weapons, firearms, (and dragons) to exist side by side, I need the wheel of fortune that can turn the battle's tide to favor one over the other, then spin it.

One such wheel was the spell [Tumblr Field]. It creates a field around the user that destabilizes and/or steers projectiles away from the center where the user is located.

The core concept of the field is to create atmospheric distortions around the bullets that nullify or greatly reduce their stability, [both types](https://bisonballistics.com/articles/bullet-stability), the atmosphere will take care of the rest.

- The field moves with the user, only creating minor disturbances in the air.
- It can take thousands of shots from any caliber, from a 20 mm anti-tank rifle to a 9 mm, without losing its protective qualities.
- The power source of the Tumblr Field is the user's own body, the energy is stored in chemical bonds, then transformed into electric energy, which is stored in a"buffer", where it could quickly be used.
- The field's ability to steer away projectiles starts decreasing once the firearm's wielder is inside the field, though that also exposes him to the dragon's stand, not something you can get away from in One Piece. Assume the worst-case scenario, the bullet being fired from just the edge of the field
- The field has to be strong enough to steer a .50 BMG AP round away even from a dragon-sized target (thankfully, dragon's aren't that big, roughly the size of a shire horse)

The technology available to create this field is the usual:

- sophisticated nanotechnology (you can build up stuff from the atomic level)
- 150-micrometer long robot flies, [based on the real ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kikiki).
- advanced swarm robotics
- more durable laser <s>KONO DIO DA!</s> diodes.

The field has to:

- Reliably able to deflect a .50 BMG AP round
- Be Relatively light
- Consume the least possible energy

**How could such field work?**

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMAP-ADS

Comment: I'm not sure the [tag:science-based] tag is the best fit here since the tech is not even close to existing in real life, might I suggest [tag:science-fiction] tag instead.

Comment: @Agrajag This is true, that's why I resorted to analogies. Look up what's the world's smallest insect.

Comment: @Mephistopheles No. You want people to take that into account, then include a description in the question. It's up to you to research the question and express it clearly. Please [edit] it, so we get the benefit of what you have in mind.

Comment: Please review our meta post about [high concept questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868).  You're basically asking us to invent the physics behind a fictional "spell" that uses fictional "nanobots" to work.  That's too broad at best, POB at worst, and fails the basic SE premise that questions should be specific and objective.  VTC OT:TB.  Also, if this "field" is powered by the spell caster's body, the force needed to deflect an anti-tank shell will draw a lethal amount of energy from the caster, killing him anyway.

Comment: No matter how you butter this up, its going to require an extraordinary amount of energy to redirect bullets enough to miss you. If the bullet can penetrate armor, your robots are going to have to somehow create something even denser and thicker to bounce or redirect it away. As it is, you have basically described a basic system. The nano bots simply push the bullets out of the way.